# How to call another class method from main class without changing the state of main class in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online

I'm using react with typescript in SharePoint framework. I want to call method in another class from main class.
I need same 1 as output in console for all three console.log calls

```
class MainPage extends React.component<Iprops, Istate>
{
    constructor(props?: Iprops, state?: Istate) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            status: 0,
        };
    }

    public firstMethod(e): void {
        this.setState({ status: 1 });
        console.log(this.state.status);
        var Obj = new AnotherClass();
        Obj.secondMethod();
    }

    public ThirdMethod(): void {
        console.log(this.state.status);
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<Iprops> {
        return <div> <button onClick={this.firstMethod.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
        </div>;
    }

}

class AnotherClass extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);
    }

    public SecondMethod(): void {
        var obj1 = new MainPage();
        console.log(obj1.state.status);
        obj1.thirdMethod();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That code is hard to read; please indent reasonably. I *think* the issue is because you're not treating `setState` as an async operation (which it is) so logging the state immediately after calling `setState` won't show the updated value, because it hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't instantiate components this way `var Obj = new AnotherClass();`. Why does `AnotherClass` even exist ? does it render something ?
Maybe you should read the react intro https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html